# Isolating text from cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've got a table that looks something like this (each cell contains 3 separate values)

[image]

I want a solution for this, and it can be done either with a formula or with VBA

If I'm doing this with VBA I would like to have 3 variables where I can store the 3 separate values (without the mm on it) I don't care about how to create a for loop that then goes through each row, I just want to know how I can store the values into variables for at least one single cell.

Otherwise I would like to know how with a formula I can create 3 new columns for each variable and then isolate the values I want to appear in the correspondent cells.

Note: sometimes there might be extra text at the beginning of the cell and this changes all the time so I can't use something like MID and tell it "After this certain amount of characters obtain the values" because I never know for sure after what amount of characters my value will be available.

Comment: are the values you want to extract the only possible digits which will occur in the cell?

Comment: Can you put a text example, i can't see images at work.

Comment: @eirikdaude No, these values are always changing, and also there might be extra text and the beginning or at the end at each cell.

Comment: Then how do you identify the values you want to extract? Are they the only digits followed by "mm" for instance?

Comment: @eirikdaude well, they always start with CATEGORY1: and like that, the issue is that the value will always be different so I don't know how I can tell it something like "Find the first and second blank space after CATEGORY1: and then extract the text in between those 2 blank spaces.

Comment: You can use `SEARCH` or `FIND` function on "CATEGORY"

Comment: You need to define _something_ distinctive about your data that identifies the parts you want to extract.  We can't do that for you, because we don't have your data.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I found a way where I look at the position of the category name, for example CATEGORY1 and then use the mid function to find the values after 9 spaces as that's the amount of characters on CATEGORY1 and then I use the IsNumeric function to find the value, is a bit messy but it worked at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a formula to find `1:`, add 3 and then return the values up to the space - lather-rinse-repeat for `2:` and `3:`

Assuming your values start at Row 2, Column A (adjust as required):

Enter into cells:
B2:

```
= LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2, FIND("1:",A2)+3, LEN(A2))," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))
```

C2:

```
= LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2, FIND("2:",A2)+3, LEN(A2))," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))
```

D2:

```
= LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2, FIND("3:",A2)+3, LEN(A2))," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure someone can shorten this formula, but this entered into cell B1 and dragged down seems to work:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s")),FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),"")) & "</s></t>","//s"))
```

It relies on the space on either side of the number (`SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","</s><s>")`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the next code. A clasic version using `InStr` to determine the start and end of the necessary string:

```
Function extractNo(strCell As String, strConst As String) As Variant
    Dim frst As Long, lst As Long, arr, k As Long, arrFin, El
    arr = Split(strCell, vbLf)
    
    ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr))
    For Each El In arr
        frst = InStr(El, strConst)
        lst = InStr(frst + Len(strConst) + 3, El, " ")
        arrFin(k) = Mid(El, frst + Len(strConst) + 3, lst - (frst + Len(strConst) + 3)): k = k + 1
        frst = 0: lst = 0
    Next
   
     extractNo = arrFin   'return the array content
End Function
```

It can be tested/called in this way:

```
Sub testExtractNo()
  Dim arr, El

    arr = extractNo(ActiveCell.value, "CATEGORY")
    For Each El In arr
        Debug.Print El
    Next
End Sub
```

But you show us a typo in the string: "CATETORY" instead of "CATEGORY". If it should be "CATETORY", just update the calling second parameter.

The code returns as many such cases exist, if the numeric part contains only a digit (0 to 9). It can be adapted for more digits, but why to do it if not requested...

**Edited**:

A second version using only arrays:

```
Function getNumb(strCell As String) As Variant
     Dim arr, El, arrFin, arrInt, k As Long
     arr = Split(strCell, vbLf)
     ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr))
     For Each El In arr
        arrInt = Split(El, " ")
        arrFin(k) = arrInt(UBound(arrInt) - 1): k = k + 1
     Next
     getNumb = arrFin
End Function
```

It can be tested in a similar way:

```
Sub testExtractNo()
  Dim arr, El

    arr = getNumb(ActiveCell.value)
    For Each El In arr
        Debug.Print El
    Next
End Sub
```

It will  also return as many numbers as lines exists in the processed cell value.

Comment: The "11" in @FaneDuru's code comes from the length of "CATEGORY"+":"+" "+1 for the starting point. If you search for something else, consider changing the number.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty I adapted the code, creating a new parameter, and now it is more elocvent without commenting the lines, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This adds all the matches to a collection, and prints them to the immediate window. If you want to do something else with them, that should be simple enough.

```
Option Explicit

Sub extract_values()
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim regMatches As Object
    Dim rangeToSearch As Range, c As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim coll As Collection
    Dim v As Variant
    
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set rangeToSearch = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = "CATEGORY\d+\: (\d+)"
    End With
    
    For Each c In rangeToSearch
        Set regMatches = regex.Execute(c.Value2)
        If regMatches.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print c.Address
            
            Set coll = New Collection
            For i = 0 To regMatches.Count - 1
                coll.Add regMatches(i).subMatches(0)
            Next i
            
            For Each v In coll
                Debug.Print v
            Next v
            Set coll = Nothing
            
        End If
        Set regMatches = Nothing
    Next c
    
End Sub
```